# Unable to open .dta files because of version

Tags: pandas, stata, dta

Version of given Stata file is 44. pandas supports importing versions 105, 108, 111 (Stata 7SE), 113 (Stata 8/9), 114 (Stata 10/11), 115 (Stata 12), 117 (Stata 13), 118 (Stata 14/15/16),and 119 (Stata 15/16, over 32,767 variables).

```
import pandas as pd
Citations2 = pd.io.stata.read_stata('Citations_2000-2010 part 2.dta')
```

I want to convert this file into csv.

Comment: Can you share your file, please?

Comment: Here is public link :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_k0MSKxpnoEy3gjqvRn9zlJ26twPobIK/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [`pyreadstat`](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat)

```
# pip install pyreadstat
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_dta('Citations_2000-2010 part 2.dta')

df.to_csv('Citations_2000-2010 part 2.csv', index=None)
```

Details:

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13569764 entries, 0 to 13569763
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column       Dtype  
---  ------       -----  
 0   patent       int64  
 1   citation     float64
 2   cit_date     object 
 3   cit_name     object 
 4   cit_kind     object 
 5   cit_country  object 
 6   category     object 
 7   citseq       object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 828.2+ MB
```

Comment: It is giving ReadstatError: This version of the file format is not supported

Comment: I used your public link. What is your `pyreadstat` version? `print(pyreadstat.__version__)`. Here 1.2.1 (and Pandas 1.5.3)

Comment: My pyreadstat version is 1.2.1  and Pandas is 1.4.4

Comment: Would you like me to convert it for you and send it back to you?

Comment: Yes. It will help me

Comment: You can download the csv file [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/957f39e9387924ac2057b78f0355fba820230418073103/648df425cabdf376ec661d475a91f24b20230418073117/5c872e?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid). To convert the file, I used the code above without any manipulation and just compress the data with zip. There are 13,569,764 records.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to convert other files also. Are you able to think, what will be probable reason?

Comment: Here is the link of two other files [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jThS9yZYoo7aPvaqjaw7r6JAlWSa8vyE/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bowX7ofl33UxJN74QhC0A0ZbbDeLyZgU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't understand, I can read all files with `pd.read_stata`. If I open binary files, I see the version is 118. Converted files [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/37ca151331d0744fbf5b7b0473ae2d2520230418082447/fea993676ae30c6323761531d1a573e820230418082512/1b14d4?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid)